# Implementing a memory efficient Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler, memory-usage, heap

I am writing a compiler in C++ 20. I am looking for ways to improve heap memory performance. For example, I can compile a **36.8 MB** source file that is just many repeating lines of:

```
let x0: string = "hello world";
let x1: string = "hello world";
let x2: string = "hello world";
let x3: string = "hello world";
...

let xn: string = "hello world";
```

According to the `massif` heap profiler, my compiler uses **785.4 MB**, so the memory overhead is **2034%**.

Currently, the compiler allocates an AST `std::shared_ptr` node for each language construct, such as a LetDeclNode, TypeDeclNode, StringLiteralNode, etc. There isn't any caching being performed.
I am hesitant to implement a caching layer because later steps in the compilation process require modifying the AST. This will be problematic when some nodes share references to a single object.

Is **2034%** or **21x**
memory overhead reasonable performance for compiling a 36 MB source file?
Are there any general techniques to solve this problem? I'm still in the early stage of compiler development, so I am okay with rewriting the parser.

EDIT:

Massif memory profile output: https://pastebin.com/d499ggBP
This file contains detailed information regarding the peeks and memory allocation/deallocation of the compiler.

Comment: [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) can be applied to your `StringLiteralNode`. Being literals, you could in fact have all these statements point to the same instance.

Comment: Good idea. What if I added a static `objhash` method to every AST node that generates a hash of the node as if it were constructed? Then, I would add a caching layer with a variadic static `create(node type, ...)` method to return a shared_ptr. It would compute the hash of the given node type and the supplied parameters, see if it already exists, and... How could I handle the case where the node is modified in general, ensuring the integrity of the cache?

Comment: A 37MB source file is not realistic for typical programming languages, so I wouldn't bother optimizing for that case. But there are ways to make data more compact. If you have a syntax *tree*, you can probably get away with unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr, eliminating control block overhead. I suspect that pointers will eat up a very large part of your memory. Sometimes, a std::variant can be more compact than OOP techniques. Sometimes, 32-bit indices can be used instead of pointers or size_t indices. Deduplication is safe for immutable data, so a constant pool might work.

Comment: This particular language will support complex macro metaprogramming. For example, ad hoc compile time test case generation for cryptographic primitives. So although the original source file won't be > ~1 MB, the actual post processed source may be quite large. The goal is to ensure reasonable performance up to around 50 MB. Anything larger will need be split into seperate jobs or somehow dealt with incrementally.

Comment: @WesleyJones does that 50MB represent the final output size? Or is that an intermediate peak size? Might it be better to consider this a tree walking interpreter for a functional program that happens to output code? And then take inspiration from lazy functional languages like thinking to avoid materialing large immutable data structures at once.

Comment: @user1937198 I'm not very familiar with tree walking interpreters. But the language I am developing needs to compile to LLVM IR to produce a binary.

Comment: If your compiling to LLVM IR consider what is the minimum amount of the executed AST that needs to be materialized to generate a single LLVM function. Then try generating function by function, discarding any parts of the AST that will not be needed to generate later functions. This likely would significantly reduce the peak memory usage. I don't know how you are generating functions from the example source code, but I assume you aren't generating MB sized functions, as the LLVM algorithms and data structures are just not designed for that scale.

Comment: If you want to be really hardcore about memory usage I'd recommend: no pointers, no OOP. Just data-oriented programming. A node is just a small type tag + indices to data stored out of band, maybe just 8 or 16 bytes total. That data can benefit from CoW. Since compilers have a clearly bounded lifetime, you don't have to track allocation metadata and can store everything in an arena that is bulk-deallocated once compilation is complete. Note that such an AST encoding is more like a bytecode format, though one that is intended for static analysis rather than direct execution.

Comment: All right, thanks for the advice. I cut memory costs by ~55% overall by reimplementing `TypeNode`'s and `LiteralNode`'s as singletons. I also restructured the base class and removed the need to inherit from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<>,` which shaved off 32 bytes from every node in the tree. I also patched some LLVM IR code generation bugs to avoid redundant memory allocations.

Comment: The compiler still isn't efficient, but it is fast enough with these changes and `-O3` and `-flto` optimization to compile the 36 MB source in ~5.7 seconds. Once I progress further, I'll do a more in-depth performance analysis to discover more areas for improvement. At this point the LLVM library is using more memory then my compiler internally.